# How straight does a creature need to move for abilities that trigger after charging towards an opponent?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, movement, attack, charge

There are certain creatures with a extra ability attached to their attack if they move a certain distance towards their opponent before attacking. Take the [Gorgon](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gorgon#content) as an example, it has the Trampling Charge ability:

> **Trampling Charge**. If the gorgon moves at least 20 feet straight toward a creature and then hits it with a gore attack on the same turn, that target must succeed on a DC 16 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone. If the target is prone, the gorgon can make one attack with its hooves against it as a bonus action.

When it says 20 feet straight towards an opponent, how straight does that need to be assuming you are using a square based grid for character locations? Do the last 20 feet of movement made by the creature need to be all in the same direction? Or would a movement pattern like east, southeast, east, southeast qualify as having moved 20 feet straight towards an opponent?

Comment: When you say the "last 4 movements", do you mean the last four 5 foot interval squares? I ask because grid-based play is not the default in 5e.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Yes. My group just about always plays on a grid.

Comment: @AllanMills You should edit your question to clarify that you are asking about grid-based movement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, by rules as written, it does not have to be the last 20 feet.  All you need to do is first move 20 feet straight towards the foe (by whatever means, potentially including flight/swimming/teleportation, should the Gorgon be given access to those movement modes) and then hit that same target with a gore attack on the same turn (not necessarily the first attack they make).  I don't believe that the 20 feet even needs to be contiguous, though that could be up for debate.

As far as what "straight" means, it's real-word reference, where you really can charge directly towards someone if there's nothing in the way.  Grid-square movement is not the default in 5e.  If you as DM choose to use grid-square optional rules in your 5e game, you're going to have to adjudicate what it means to be moving "straight towards" some target - 5e has a lot of vague areas, and the local DM is expected to adjudicate them.  For consistency's sake, there should probably be at least one path between any two points to count as "straight towards' but aside from that it's up to the DM.